# Как вызвать поиск по странице через консоль?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

При нажатии клавиш Ctrl+F в браузере выскакивает панель для поиска по странице. Возможно ли эту панель какой нибудь командой вызвать через консоль браузера?

P.S. Ок, по всей видимости вызвать панель поиска простой командой нельзя. Но может же быть тогда скрипт на JS, который при вводе в консоль браузера создаст и выведет свою подобную панель?

Comment: Возможно, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, данный метод **НЕ** показывает панель поиска

Comment: @Grundy Ну, я не был уверен, насколько нужна именно панель поиска, а не результат её работы.

Comment: У меня с данным скриптом такая ошибка http://img.alexodlw.beget.tech/2022-03-04_175020.png ... как только ставлю скрипт на боевой хост. В html отлично работает

Answer (score 5):

Возможно, чуть позже я адаптирую скрипт для вставки на любую страницу. Но вы можете сделать это и сами. Это не так уж и сложно, так как скрипт не требует никаких зависимостей и, по идее, должен работать во всех современных браузерах.

```js
/* Этим параметром задаем минимальное количество введенных букв, от которого начинается поиск */
const minCharsToSearch = 3;

const 
  /* Функция-обёртка над методом Observable#addEventListener() */
  on = (o, e, c) => o.addEventListener(e, c, false),
  /* Функция-обёртка на последовательный вызов методов Event#preventDefault() и Event#stopPropagation() */
  stop = e => ['preventDefault', 'stopPropagation'].map(f => e[f]()),
  /* Функция добавляет класс с элементу o */
  addCls = (o, c) => (o.classList.add(c), o),
  /* Функция удаляет класс c из элемента o */
  remCls = (o, c) => (o.classList.remove(c), o),
  /* Функция создает новый элемент <t> */
  newEl = t => document.createElement(t),
  /* Функция добавляет элемент o в конец элемента p */
  append = (p, o) => (p.appendChild(o), o),
  /* Функция возвращает верхнюю позицию скролла страницы в пикселях */
  pageTop = () => document.scrollingElement.scrollTop,
  /* Функция возвращает нижнюю позицию скролла страницы в пикселях */
  pageBottom = () => pageTop() + document.documentElement.clientHeight;

const /* Форма поиска */
  form = document.forms[0],
  /* Поле ввода поисковой фразы */
  input = form.querySelector('input'),
  /* Надпись с лупой */
  search = form.querySelector('.search'),
  /* Кнопка отчистки поля ввода поисковой фразы */
  clear = form.querySelector('.clear'),
  /* Надпись с результатами поиска (например, "1 из 15") */
  output = form.querySelector('.output'),
  /* Кнопка перехода к следующему результату */
  next = form.querySelector('.next'),
  /* Кнопка перехода к предыдущему результату */
  prev = form.querySelector('.prev'),
  /* Корневой элемент с информацией, в которой будет осуществляться поиск */
  content = document.querySelector('.content');

/* Обработка разных событий */
on(form, 'submit', onSubmit);
on(form, 'input', onInput);
on(window, 'resize', onResize);

on(clear, 'click', doClear);
on(output, 'click', curPosLast);
on(next, 'click', goNext);
on(prev, 'click', goPrev);

function onSubmit(e) {
  /* Применяя форму не стоит перезагружать страницу */
  stop(e);
}

let /* Элемент setTimeout, отвечающий за выжидание паузы при вводе фразы.
       В противном случае поиск будет осуществляться с вводом каждой буквы. */
  timeout,
  /* Сюда помещаются результаты поиска */
  searchResult = [],
  /* Сюда помещается индекс активного результата */
  searchResultActive = null;

/* Обработчик ввода */
function onInput(e) {
  /* Отменяем действия браузера по обработке ввода */
  stop(e);
  /* Если поле фразы не пустое */
  if (input.value) {
    /* Прячем надпись с лупой */
    remCls(search, 'visible');
    /* На месте фразы с лупой отобразим кнопку отчистки поля */
    addCls(clear, 'visible');
  } else {
  /* или */
    /* отчищаем надпись с результатами поиска */
    output.innerHTML = ``;
    /* Отображаем надпись с лупой */
    addCls(search, 'visible');
    /* Убираем кнопку отчистки поля фразы */
    remCls(clear, 'visible');
  }
  /* Для начала убираем возможность тыкать по кнопкам 
     "предыдущий результат" и "следующий результат" */
  remCls(next, 'enabled');
  remCls(prev, 'enabled');
  /* Если был неотработанный таймаут, отменяем его */
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  /* Устанавливаем новый таймаут */
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    /* удалим ссылку на выполненый таймаут */
    timeout = null;
    /* Фраза даля поиска */
    const searchValue = input.value;
    /* Если фраза содержит достаточное количество букв */
    if (searchValue.length >= minCharsToSearch) {
      /* Осуществляем поиск */
      doSearch(searchValue);
    } else {
    /* или */
      /* выводим сообщение */
      output.innerHTML = `от 3х букв`;
    }
  }, 200);
}

/* Функция осуществляет поиск */
function doSearch(searchValue) {
  searchResultActive = null;
  searchResult = findAll(searchValue);
  if (searchResult.length) {
    let top = pageTop(),
      found = 0;
    for (const [idx, res] of searchResult.entries()) {
      if (res.rects.every(rect => rect.top > top)) {
        found = idx;
        break;
      }
    }
    setActive(found);
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = `совпадений нет`;
  }
}

/* Обработчик кнопки отчистки поля ввода фразы */
function doClear() {
  searchResultActive = null;
  searchResult = [];
  input.value = '';
  /* Отображаем надпись с лупой */
  addCls(search, 'visible');
  /* Скрываем кнопку отчистки поля ввода */
  remCls(clear, 'visible');
  /* Убираем возможность тыкать по кнопкам 
     "предыдущий результат" и "следующий результат" */
  remCls(next, 'enabled');
  remCls(prev, 'enabled');
  /* Удаляем все подсветки результатов поиска */
  document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach(hl => hl.remove());
  /* Отчистка надписи с результатами поиска */
  output.innerHTML = ``;
}

/* Обработчик кнопки перехода к следующему результату */
function goNext() {
  setActive(searchResultActive + 1);
}

/* Обработчик кнопки перехода к предыдущему результату */
function goPrev() {
  setActive(searchResultActive - 1);
}

/* Обработчик изменения размеров видимой части страницы */
function onResize() {
  setTimeout(
    () =>
      /* Для каждого результата поиска */
      searchResult.map(
        res =>
          /* Установка новых координат прямоугольников, выделяющих результаты поиска */
          (res.rects = getRects(res.range).map((rect, i) => (setRectSize(res.hls[i], rect), rect)))
      ),
    1
  );
}

/* Функция, которая, собственно, осуществляет поиск и возвращает все результаты поиска */
function findAll(text) {
  /* Удаляем все подсветки с предыдущего поиска (если есть) */
  document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach(hl => hl.remove());
  /* Из корневого элемента информации, где осуществаляется поиск,
     берем только текствую состовляющую.
     Здесь textContent подходит лучше чем innerText. */
  const { textContent } = content;
  /* Из поисковой фразы как-то смастерим регулярку для поиска по контенту */
  const rx = new RegExp(text.replace(/([-.*+?^${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1').replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+'), 'ig');
  /* Предварительный массив результатов */
  const res = [];
  /* В эту переменную сохраняется текущий результат поиска регулярки */
  let match;
  /* Пока регулярка даёт результаты */
  while ((match = rx.exec(textContent))) {
    /* Записываем результаты в массив */
    res.push({
      /* Индекс начала найденного выражения */ startAbs: match.index,
      startNode: null,
      startOfs: null,
      /* Индекс конца найденного выражения */
      endAbs: match.index + match[0].length,
      endNode: null,
      endOfs: null,
      range: null,
      rects: null,
      hls: null,
    });
  }
  /* Далее создаём иерархичный гулятор по корневому элементу контента,
     фильтруем только текстовые ноды */
  const walk = document.createTreeWalker(content, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);

  let idx = 0; /* Индекс текущей находки текста */
  let len = res.length; /* Длинна массива с находками */
  let curStart = 0; /* Индекст позиции находки в текущем текстовом блоке */
  let node; /* Текстовая нода, в которой начинается находка */
  /* Пока не кончились находки или не кончились текстовые ноды на странице */
  while (idx < len && (node = walk.nextNode())) {
    /* Считаем конечную позицию текущей ноды */
    const curEnd = curStart + node.textContent.length;
    let found = false; /* Флаг найденной ноды */
    do {
      found = false; /* Устанавливаем флаг найденной ноды в "не найдено" */
      const curRes = res[idx]; /* Текущая находка */
      const { startAbs, endAbs } = curRes; /* Абсолютные позиции начала и конца находки */
      /* Если текущая находка еще не имеет начальной ноды,
         при этом текущая начальная позиция меньше абсолютной начальной позиции находки
         и абсолютная начальная позиция меньше конечной позиции текущей ноды */
      if (!curRes.startNode && curStart <= startAbs && startAbs < curEnd) {
        /* то: */
        /* устанавливаем текущей находке начальную ноду */
        curRes.startNode = node;
        /* устанавливаем текущей находке относительную позицию начала находки */
        curRes.startOfs = startAbs - curStart;
      }
      /* Если текущая находка уже имеет начальную ноду,
         при этом текущая начальная позиция меньше абсолютной конечной позиции находки
         и абсолютная конечная позиция меньше конечной позиции текущей ноды */
      if (curRes.startNode && curStart < endAbs && endAbs < curEnd) {
        /* то; */
        /* Обхявляем диапазон находки */
        const range = document.createRange();
        curRes.range = range;
        /* устанавливаем текущей находке конечную ноду */
        curRes.endNode = node;
        /* устанавливаем текущей находке относительную позицию конца находки */
        curRes.endOfs = endAbs - curStart;
        /* Устанавливаем диапазону начальную позицию (сама нода, и относительная позиция внутри ноды) */
        range.setStart(curRes.startNode, curRes.startOfs);
        /* Устанавливаем диапазону конечную позицию (сама нода, и относительная позиция внутри ноды) */
        range.setEnd(curRes.endNode, curRes.endOfs);
        /* Устанавливаем текущей находке все <div>ы подсветки, где: */
        curRes.hls = (curRes.rects = getRects(range)) /* зоны находки (в пикселях) для дальнейшей подсветки, */
          .map(rect =>
            append(
              document.body /* каждой зоне создаём по одному <div>, которому */,
              setRectSize(addCls(newEl('div'), 'highlight'), rect)
            )
          ); /* устанавливаем размеры зоны и className=highlight */
        found = true; /* Устанавливаем флаг текущей находки на "найдено" */
        idx++; /* Инкремент индекса текущей находки */
      }
      /* Выполняем цикл пока найдено и пока есть ещё находки */
    } while (found && idx < len);
    /* Устанавливаем позицию старта для следующих итераций цикла */
    curStart = curEnd;
  }
  /* Возвращаем массив со всеми находками */
  return res;
}

/* Функция устанавливает активную находку по индексу находки */
function setActive(resNum) {
  /* Для начала снимем классы со всех активных в прошлом подсветок */
  document.querySelectorAll('.highlight.active').forEach(hl => remCls(hl, 'active'));
  const res = searchResult[resNum]; /* текущая активная находка */
  const top = pageTop(); /* позиция скроллинга верхней границы видимой области */
  const bottom = pageBottom(); /* позиция скроллинга нижней границы видимой области */
  /* Если текущая активная находка заходит за пределы видимой области скроллинга */
  if (!res.rects.every(rect => rect.top > top && rect.top + rect.height < bottom)) {
    /* Находим минимальную верхнюю зону видимости находки */
    const minRectTop = Math.min(...res.rects.map(rect => rect.top));
    /* Находим максимальную нижнюю зону видимости находки */
    const maxRectBottom = Math.max(...res.rects.map(rect => rect.top + rect.height));
    /* Определяем центр между верхней и нижней зонами находки */
    const centerRect = (maxRectBottom + minRectTop) / 2;
    /* Определяем центр между верхней и нижней границ текущий видимой области скроллинга */
    const centerScr = (bottom - top) / 2;
    /* Устанавливаем скроллинг на разницу между двумя центрами */
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = centerRect - centerScr;
  }
  /* Устанавливаем новую активную находку */
  searchResultActive = resNum;
  /* Выдаляем элементы, подсвечивающие находку классом active */
  res.hls.forEach(hl => addCls(hl, 'active'));
  /* Длина массива с находками */
  const len = searchResult.length;
  /* Устанавливаем значения надписи, указывающей на номер находки */
  output.innerHTML = `${resNum + 1} из ${len}`;
  /* Если есть хоть одна находка */
  if (len > 1) {
    /* Делаем активной кнопку Next если не последняя находка или неактивной в противном случае */
    (resNum < len - 1 ? addCls : remCls)(next, 'enabled');
    /* Делаем активной кнопку Prev если не первая находка или неактивной в противном случае */
    (resNum > 0 ? addCls : remCls)(prev, 'enabled');
  }
}

/* Устанавливаем позицию курсора <input> (в строке поиска) */
function curPosLast() {
  const len = input.value.length;
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(len, len);
}

/* Функция возвращает все зоны rect внутри диапазона range */
function getRects(range) {
  return [...range.getClientRects()]
    .map(rect => ['left', 'width', 'top', 'height'].reduce((r, k) => ((r[k] = rect[k]), r), {}))
    .map(rect => ((rect.top += pageTop()), rect));
}

/* Функция задаёт элементу размеры зоны rect */
function setRectSize(el, rect) {
  Object.assign(el.style, Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(rect).map(([key, val]) => [key, val + 'px'])));
  return el;
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
html,body{ margin: 0; scroll-behavior: smooth; }

form {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #ccc;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: calc( 100vw - 10px - 6rem);
  height: calc( 3rem - 10px);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ad1d1d;
}

.input:focus,.input:focus-within,.input:active {
  border: 1px solid #c58e37;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #c58e37;
}

.input * {
  margin: 0; 
  padding:0;
  height: calc( 3rem - 12px);
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input input {
  border: none;
  width: calc( 100vw - 16rem - 12px - 6rem);
  height: calc( 3rem - 12px);
  outline: none;
}
.input .search,
.input .clear,
.input .next,
.input .prev,
.input .output {
  user-select: none;
}
.search {
  display:none;
  width: 3rem;
  height: calc(3rem - 12px);
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2rem 0 0 0;
}

.clear {
  width: calc(3rem - 20px);
  height: calc(3rem - 24px);
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  margin: 6px 10px 8px 10px;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background: #8888;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.clear:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#f008;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block;
}

.output {
  width: 7rem;
  text-align: right;
  height: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(3rem - 12px);
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  cursor: text;
}

.input button{
  width: 3rem;
  height: calc(3rem - 11px);
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #888;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
  outline: none;
  margin: -1px 0 1px 0;
}

.input button.enabled {
  pointer-events: all;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

.input button.enabled:focus{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px #f84;
}

.input button.enabled:active{
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
  border-left: 2px solid #888;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}


.content{
  clear:both;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.highlight{
  background: #ff04;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ff0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

.highlight.active {
  background: #f844;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #f00;
}
```

```html
<form><div class="input"><label for="search" class="search visible"></label><span class="clear">✖</span><input id="search" type="text"/><span class="output"></span><button class="prev">⫷</button><button class="next">⫸</button></div></form>
    
    <div class="content">
      <p>Ясность нашей позиции очевидна: укрепление и развитие внутренней структуры является качественно новой ступенью экспериментов, поражающих по своей масштабности и грандиозности. Как принято считать, сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы формируют глобальную экономическую сеть и при этом - описаны максимально подробно. В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что укрепление и развитие внутренней структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений. А ещё тщательные исследования конкурентов, превозмогая сложившуюся непростую экономическую ситуацию, рассмотрены исключительно в разрезе маркетинговых и финансовых предпосылок. Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: убеждённость некоторых оппонентов требует определения и уточнения вывода текущих активов.</p>
      <p>Не следует, однако, забывать, что современная методология разработки предоставляет широкие возможности для форм воздействия. Предварительные выводы неутешительны: реализация намеченных плановых заданий не оставляет шанса для системы массового участия. Принимая во внимание показатели успешности, синтетическое тестирование, в своём классическом представлении, допускает внедрение стандартных подходов!</p>
      <p>Высокий уровень вовлечения представителей целевой аудитории является четким доказательством простого факта: сплочённость команды профессионалов предопределяет высокую востребованность глубокомысленных рассуждений. Современные технологии достигли такого уровня, что понимание сути ресурсосберегающих технологий однозначно определяет каждого участника как способного принимать собственные решения касаемо экспериментов, поражающих по своей масштабности и грандиозности. Противоположная точка зрения подразумевает, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира будут объявлены нарушающими общечеловеческие нормы этики и морали. Противоположная точка зрения подразумевает, что базовые сценарии поведения пользователей ассоциативно распределены по отраслям. Сложно сказать, почему сторонники тоталитаризма в науке, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского типа политической культуры, будут в равной степени предоставлены сами себе.</p>
      <p>Принимая во внимание показатели успешности, консультация с широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки кластеризации усилий. Имеется спорная точка зрения, гласящая примерно следующее: тщательные исследования конкурентов освещают чрезвычайно интересные особенности картины в целом, однако конкретные выводы, разумеется, в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Также как экономическая повестка сегодняшнего дня играет определяющее значение для поэтапного и последовательного развития общества. Разнообразный и богатый опыт говорит нам, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий способствует подготовке и реализации существующих финансовых и административных условий.</p>
      <p>В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции выявляет срочную потребность позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач! Господа, постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности играет важную роль в формировании новых принципов формирования материально-технической и кадровой базы. Задача организации, в особенности же внедрение современных методик предполагает независимые способы реализации стандартных подходов. Сложно сказать, почему представители современных социальных резервов будут объявлены нарушающими общечеловеческие нормы этики и морали. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании системы массового участия. Есть над чем задуматься: интерактивные прототипы будут ограничены исключительно образом мышления.</p>
      <p>Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: сплочённость команды профессионалов не даёт нам иного выбора, кроме определения глубокомысленных рассуждений. Лишь независимые государства, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского типа политической культуры, будут призваны к ответу. В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что перспективное планирование напрямую зависит от экспериментов, поражающих по своей масштабности и грандиозности. Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: существующая теория способствует повышению качества первоочередных требований. Учитывая ключевые сценарии поведения, внедрение современных методик играет определяющее значение для первоочередных требований.</p>
      <p>Имеется спорная точка зрения, гласящая примерно следующее: непосредственные участники технического прогресса смешаны с не уникальными данными до степени совершенной неузнаваемости, из-за чего возрастает их статус бесполезности. В частности, новая модель организационной деятельности, в своём классическом представлении, допускает внедрение как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений. Но сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы своевременно верифицированы. Ясность нашей позиции очевидна: граница обучения кадров не даёт нам иного выбора, кроме определения поставленных обществом задач. Не следует, однако, забывать, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности напрямую зависит от новых принципов формирования материально-технической и кадровой базы. Являясь всего лишь частью общей картины, базовые сценарии поведения пользователей могут быть представлены в исключительно положительном свете.</p>
      <p>Следует отметить, что повышение уровня гражданского сознания создаёт предпосылки для поставленных обществом задач. Кстати, стремящиеся вытеснить традиционное производство, нанотехнологии представляют собой не что иное, как квинтэссенцию победы маркетинга над разумом и должны быть заблокированы в рамках своих собственных рациональных ограничений.</p>
      <p>Граница обучения кадров способствует повышению качества как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений! Равным образом, высокотехнологичная концепция общественного уклада является качественно новой ступенью направлений прогрессивного развития. Ясность нашей позиции очевидна: современная методология разработки обеспечивает актуальность соответствующих условий активизации. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление, в своём классическом представлении, допускает внедрение экспериментов, поражающих по своей масштабности и грандиозности. С учётом сложившейся международной обстановки, базовый вектор развития обеспечивает актуальность распределения внутренних резервов и ресурсов.</p>
      <p>С учётом сложившейся международной обстановки, выбранный нами инновационный путь напрямую зависит от системы обучения кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям. В своём стремлении повысить качество жизни, они забывают, что сплочённость команды профессионалов позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития.</p>
      <p>Ясность нашей позиции очевидна: экономическая повестка сегодняшнего дня способствует повышению качества форм воздействия. Прежде всего, реализация намеченных плановых заданий играет важную роль в формировании поставленных обществом задач. Также как консультация с широким активом предполагает независимые способы реализации как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений. Банальные, но неопровержимые выводы, а также элементы политического процесса освещают чрезвычайно интересные особенности картины в целом, однако конкретные выводы, разумеется, ассоциативно распределены по отраслям. Каждый из нас понимает очевидную вещь: внедрение современных методик способствует подготовке и реализации приоритизации разума над эмоциями. В целом, конечно, внедрение современных методик предопределяет высокую востребованность благоприятных перспектив.</p>
      <p>Безусловно, курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект однозначно определяет каждого участника как способного принимать собственные решения касаемо направлений прогрессивного развития. Есть над чем задуматься: действия представителей оппозиции могут быть превращены в посмешище, хотя само их существование приносит несомненную пользу обществу. Внедрение современных методик требует определения и уточнения поэтапного и последовательного развития общества. Независимые государства формируют глобальную экономическую сеть и при этом - преданы социально-демократической анафеме. Как принято считать, диаграммы связей лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и обнародованы.</p>
      <p>Предварительные выводы неутешительны: курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект предопределяет высокую востребованность вывода текущих активов. С другой стороны, новая модель организационной деятельности выявляет срочную потребность поставленных обществом задач.</p>
      <p>Господа, разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление в значительной степени обусловливает важность позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Мы вынуждены отталкиваться от того, что выбранный нами инновационный путь в значительной степени обусловливает важность прогресса профессионального сообщества. Следует отметить, что повышение уровня гражданского сознания требует анализа распределения внутренних резервов и ресурсов.</p>
      <p>Разнообразный и богатый опыт говорит нам, что укрепление и развитие внутренней структуры создаёт предпосылки для системы массового участия. Имеется спорная точка зрения, гласящая примерно следующее: непосредственные участники технического прогресса и по сей день остаются уделом либералов, которые жаждут быть объявлены нарушающими общечеловеческие нормы этики и морали. Господа, семантический разбор внешних противодействий не даёт нам иного выбора, кроме определения как самодостаточных, так и внешне зависимых концептуальных решений. Принимая во внимание показатели успешности, повышение уровня гражданского сознания не даёт нам иного выбора, кроме определения вывода текущих активов.</p>
    </div>
```

Чуть не забыл упомянуть тонкий момент. Бэкграунд у текстовых блоков должен быть прозрачный. В противном случае, подсветка найденного текста не будет работать, так как блоки подсветки располагаются под текстовой нодой.

Comment: Приношу извинения за формат blackbox. Я постараюсь в течении для прокомментировать каждую строчку досконально. Можно легко переделать на jQuery, vue или react.

Comment: Теперь получилось прокомментировать весь код. Комментирование заняло в сумме больше 4х часов рабочего времени.

Comment: P.S. Если нашли баги работы скрипта в каком-либо современном браузере, напишите о баге в комментариях. Сток минусующих. А сам пока явных ошибок не нашел.

Comment: В IE11 не работает "Функция-обёртка над методом Element" ругается на "$ = (..."

Comment: @Андрей у меня нет возможности установить IE11. Убрал из кода `$` и `$$`. Может, так заработает?